# Apache redirect web to other host on network

Tags: server, apache2, proxy, redirect

I'm trying to set up one of my hosts as a sort of master web manager. It'll host the majority of my web content, but certain items have already been set up on other hosts and I'm quite content to leave them there.

 I'm trying to set up virtual hosts on the main web server for the specific domains that will need to be routed, but I can't seem to figure it out.

 in the 000-default.conf file, I've tried putting in 

`Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
/Proxy>
ProxyPass / (broke the link because of reputation. It's http:)//192.168.0.119/
ProxyPassReverse / (broke the link because of reputation. It's http:)//192.168.0.119/
Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow fom all
/Location>`


 I also tried using


`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.(asterisk)) (broke the link because of reputation. It's http:)//192.168.0.119/$1 [P]`

And a few other variations of the above. Some would redirect to the IP rather than proxy the connection, so only local clients would be able to access the web page. Others wouldn't redirect or proxy at all. No errors or warnings in apaches logs. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Could have sworn I used this before, but
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://192.168.0.119/ [P]`

 does the trick just fine.

Also, for anyone wanting to so HTTPS -> HTTPS proxies, you'll need to put the proxies in default-ssl.conf or other appropriately configured host file.